# How to find the source definition of an environment variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

There is a global environment variable that was declared somewhere in my OS. Let's say is called `FOOBAR`

When I echo it, I receive a proper output:

```
$ echo $FOOBAR
localhost%6200
```

I want to know where is defined because I need to update its value for certain process. Currently, I am declaring this value manually in a script before executing my processes, just to override it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# other comands...
export FOOBAR=localhost%16200
# rest of script
```

Still, I'm curious about why I cannot find the definition of this variable.

I have gone through several posts like these:

- [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117467) (trying to see other places where to find the environment variable)
- [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810/1065197)
- [How to determine where an environment variable came from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813)

I've looked into `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, scripts in `/etc/profile.d/`, I've executed several commands and tried different variations, like searching in all `/etc` and `/home/MyUser` and still no luck.

The only hint I got is this output from searching through `/home/MyUser`:

```
$ find /home/MyUser -type f -exec grep -F FOOBAR {} +
... lines ...
/home/MyUser/.xsession-errors:dbus-update-activation-environment: setting FOOBAR=localhost%6200
```

Then I tried looking at the variables defined for dbus by using this command

```
$ systemctl --user show-environment
... among other variables ...
FOOBAR=localhost%6200
```

There I see it!

How can I track this environment variable definition?

Comment: Why are you hiding the name of the variable? The name may not be important to you, but someone gave it a name for a reason, use it. Is it an X variable? if so why are you wanting to change it?

Comment: @j-money is a variable from a closed source program we should use in the company for one of our clients.

Comment: Ask the creators of the program then,